# Bulk load csv files into postgres

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio

I'm looking for a way in which I can bulk load my CSV files into my Postgres database. I'm trying to achieve this through Visual Studio or any other ETL tool like Talend, etc. I haven't found anything anywhere online regarding this. Is this not possible? I'm pretty new to Postgres so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.  If you want a purely visual tool solution, I would recommend PgAdmin 4, which is described here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/pgadmin-4/reference/online-documentation/4.13/import_export_data.html

Or, if you want a command-line solution, which will allow you to script your solution, you can either use:

The COPY command: https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/10/pg/sql-copy.html

e.g.

```
COPY mytable (name, age, location)
FROM '/home/user/files/myfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

or the the psql \copy command: https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/10/pg/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY

e.g.

```
\COPY mytable (name, age, location) FROM '/home/user/files/myfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

You can see that they're almost identical, except the first one can be run alongside any SQL commands, including in PgAdmin or from another application, and the second example can only be run using the psql command-line tool.

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and 
provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Thom the import-export tool can only process one file at a time maybe I wasn't clear in the question. I have multiple CSV files that I want to load into the database. I can upload one by one using the import wizard. I'm looking for a solution using any ETL that would enable me to create a process and load all the files together.